# Adding a "%" to a route using React-Router causes the app to crash

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm using `react-router-dom`. I've found that when a user modifies the querystring of the current page to add a final "%", the app crashes and the following error is printed in the console:

```
URIError: Pathname "/search%" could not be decoded. This is likely caused by an invalid percent-encoding
```

I've found in their GitHub repository that the error is related to some issue they have with the `history` dependency, but not fix for it.

Does anyone know what can be done about it? I don't seem to find a way to take control over the parsing of the URL.

Thanks.

Comment: what's the real problem here, you want to remove the "%" from the url or do you want to encode it? What does "when a user modifies the query string" mean, are your users supposed to write the url's themselves?

Comment: @VelimirTchatchevsky they are not supposed to, but they can, and we'd like to be able to handle the error in that case instead of letting the app crash

Comment: In my personal opinion that's an overkill, if the user is purposefully misusing the application you shoudn't care about the state he ends up in - besides covering any security concerns of course. Otherwise you can handle incorrect links with a rewrite rule from your server I guess.